# Minimum of random variables independent of index

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $T_1, \ldots, T_n$ be mutually independent random variables with exponential distributions of rate $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ respectively. Define $V= \min T_i $ and a random variable $I$ that assumes value $i$ if and only if $V=T_i$.

How can we prove that $V$ and $I$ are independent?

The hard part is is dealing with a variable that is discrete and other that isn't. So I thought of considering independence as $$ P(I \in A,  V \in B) =P(I \in A) P(V \in B)$$
which only needs to be proven for sets $A=\{i\}$ and $B=(-\infty, t]$. But I don't know what to do once I get to
$$P(I=i, V \leq t)$$

Comment: Are the $T_i$ mutually independent random variables? With regard to your question about showing $V$ and $I$ to be independent, you could try showing that the _conditional_ distribution of $V$ _given_ that $I = i$ is the same as the _unconditional_ distribution of $V$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll rely here on a result that you probably know: if $X_1\ldots,X_n$ are independent exponential variables with rates $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, then $V:=\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda:=\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n$.  (If you haven't seen this, try proving it -- it is a pretty straight-forward proof, if you induct on $n$.)

Given this: we can immediately see that
$$
P(V\leq v)=1-e^{-\lambda v},\qquad\lambda:=\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n.
$$

What if we condition on $I=i$?  Let $\lambda'=\lambda-\lambda_i$, and let $V':=\min\{T_j\mid j\neq i\}$. Note that $V'$ is independent of $T_i$, and is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda'$.

Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
P(V\leq v, I=i)&=P(T_i\leq v, V'\geq T_i)\\
&=\int_0^vP(V'\geq t_i\mid T_i=t_i)\lambda_ie^{-\lambda_it_i}\,dt_i\\
&=\int_0^vP(V'\geq t_i)\lambda_ie^{-\lambda_it_i}\,dt_i\\
&=\int_0^ve^{-\lambda't_i}\lambda_ie^{-\lambda_it_i}\,dt_i\\
&=\int_0^v\lambda_ie^{-\lambda t_i}\,dt_i\\
&=\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda v}).
\end{align*}
$$
Similar computations show that
$$
P(I=i)=\int_0^{\infty}\lambda_ie^{-\lambda t_i}\,dt_i=\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda}.
$$
So, all told,
$$
P(V\leq v\mid I=i)=1-e^{-\lambda v}=P(V\leq v),
$$
and therefore $V$ and $I$ are independent.

**UPDATE:** Adding more detail on the initial integration.

This is actually a very standard way of dealing with joint distributions of random variables; I'll show you a derivation here that leverages the fact that $T_i$ and $V'$ are independent, to go directly to the second integral.

Note that $P(T_i\leq v, V'\geq T_i)$ is written entirely in terms of continuous variables. Also, it can be written as $P((T_i,V')\in\Lambda)$, where $\Lambda$ is the 2-space triangle
$$
\Lambda:=\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq x\leq v, y\geq x\}.
$$
Therefore we can write
$$
P(T_i\leq v, V'\geq T_i)=\iint_{\Lambda}f_{T_i,V'}(x,y)\,dy\,dx,
$$
where $f_{T_i,V'}(x,y)$ is the joint density function of $(T_i,V')$. Now, $T_i$ and $V'$ are independent, so we can write
$$
f_{T_i,V'}(x,y)=f_{T_i}(x)f_{V'}(y).
$$
So,
$$
\begin{align*}
P(T_i\leq v, V'\geq T_i)&=\iint_{\Lambda}f_{T_i}(x)\,f_{V'}(y)\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_0^v\int_x^\infty f_{T_i}(x)\,f_{V'}(y)\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_0^v f_{T_i}(x)\int_x^{\infty}f_{V'}(y)\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_0^v f_{T_i}(x)P(V'\geq x)\,dx
\end{align*}
$$
Note that if we didn't have independence, we would instead have used the conditional density
$$
f_{T_i,V'}(x,y)=f_{V'\mid T_i=x}(y)f_{T_i}(x),
$$
where $f_{V'\mid T_i=x}$ is the conditional density of $V'$ given $T_i=x$.

That's where the initial integral came from with the conditional probability.

Comment: That's great. However, I don't know how to prove that $T_i \leq v $ can be decomposed in $T_i = t_i $ for all corresponding values of $t_i$ and then integrated. If there was a numerable amount of $t_i $ this would be a direct application of a property of the probability measure (the measure of a numerable union of disjoint events being the numerable sum of the measures) but I don't know how that is handled in the continuous case

Comment: @Emilio Take a look at the update; hope this helps.

Comment: I know it's a standard technique, but I'm not familiarized and find it difficult to prove the details are correct. Especially when the concept of joint density is involved, because I don't understand it completely. I think it can be tricky. Anyhow, I think your answer is complete and very well written, thanks for tour time. I like the update because it doesn't make me think of something like $P(T_i = t_i)$, which actually is zero and must be interpreted in terms of density